# SBT SDK Blogs and Activities API error

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I setup the Social Business Toolkit against our development system. All APIs are working correct, except for the Blog and Activities API.
For both i recieve within the Java APIs the following error:

```
org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Document
```

The blog request url from the sbt is:

```
http://example.com/service/proxy/connections/blogs/homepage/feed/blogs/atom?ps=5&dojo.preventCache=13
```

But correct would be:

```
http://example.com/service/proxy/connections/blogs/atom?ps=5&dojo.preventCache=13
```

Any idea why that happens?

Comment: I asked a teammate to look at this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog path is customizable per each IBM Connection installation: to support different blogs homepages, there is a parameter exposed on the BlogService API.

To change the default, try:

```
BlogService svc = ...
svc.defaultHomepageHandle = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Lorenzo's answer is correct, most installations use homepage as the blog handle, but you can configure it using the defaultHomepageHandle member variable in the BlogService.

Just a brief comment, maybe it's better to use the setHomepageHandle() method instead.